# Can you save an array of questions to mySQL along with two strings?

Tags: javascript, mysql, axios

I have a function passing Title(string), Description(string) and Questions(array) to my database. However, when I parse the data I only recieve the title and description. I have tried various methods of saving data to the questions array, but using inspector tools (specifically the Network tab) I can see that the Questions array is part of the Payload. Does that mean I am saving the data incorrectly, or am I parsing it wrong? Here is the save function:

```
    const saveTest = () => {
        const updatedTestData = {
            title: testData.title,
            description: testData.description,
            questions: testData.questions.map(question => ({
                text: question.text,
                type: 'text',
                id: question.id,
            })),
        };

        axios.post('/api/tests', updatedTestData)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data.message);
                alert("Test Saved! " + JSON.stringify(response.data));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error saving test:', error);
            });
    }
```

Here is the parsing:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedTeaserTitle) {
            axios.get('/api/tests/all')
                .then((response) => {
                    const filteredData = response.data.filter(test => test.title === selectedTeaserTitle);
                    setData(filteredData);
                    console.log(filteredData);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching tests:', error);
                });
        }
    }, [selectedTeaserTitle]);
```

And here is my TestController:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
public function storeData(Request $request): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'questions' => 'array', // Validate that 'questions' is an array
    ]);

    $test = Test::createTest($validatedData);

    // Check if 'questions' data is present in the request
    if ($request->has('questions')) {
        $questions = $request->input('questions');

        // Store the questions data related to the test
        foreach ($questions as $questionData) {
            // Create a new question and associate it with the test
            $question = new Question(['text' => $questionData['text']]);
            $test->questions()->save($question);
        }
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Test created successfully', 'test' => $test], 201);
}


public function getTests(): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
    {
        // Retrieve data from the 'tests' table
        $tests = Test::all(); // This fetches all test records from the database. Only need one at a time tho

        return response()->json($tests);
    }
}
```

I can see that the questions are part of the payload, but they are not visible in the Preview or Response tabs. My `alert(JSON.stringify())` is also only showing the title, description, created date and updated date. I have even created seperate Models, Controllers and a table for the questions array, but it seems to me that it shouldn't be so difficult. What am I missing?

Comment: To clarify... Are you indicating that you've confirmed that the request to `'/api/tests'` contains the data you expect, but the resulting response from that URL does not contain the data you expect?

Comment: That's the way I understood it, yes

Comment: In that case it sounds like you'll want to examine and debug the server-side code.  Nothing in the code shown is interacting with a database.

Comment: As in my TestController? Sorry I'm new to databases and such, I'm not so sure which information you need

Comment: Well, if the problem is that the code which writes to or reads from the database isn't doing what you expect, then you'd want to examine and debug the code which writes to or reads from the database.  Or if the problem is that the code which receives and responds to the AJAX request isn't doing what you expect, then you'd want to examine and debug the code which receives and responds to the AJAX request.  From your description it doesn't sound like the code shown in the question is failing in any way, but rather some other code somewhere else is.  Unless you can clarify otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug to the server, I think the problem on the server is in the test and question creation itself

```php
public function storeData(Request $request): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'questions' => 'array',
        'questions.*.text' => 'required|string',
        'questions.*.type' => 'required|string',
        'questions.*.id' => 'required|integer',
    ]);

    $test = Test::createTest(
        Arr::only($validatedData, ['title', 'description'])
    );

    // Check if 'questions' data is present in the request

    $questions = $request->get('questions', []);

    if (count($questions)) {
        $test->questions()->createMany(array_column($questions, 'text'));


        // OR save many
        $questions = array_map(function ($text) {
            return new Question(['text' => $text]);
        }, array_column($questions, 'text');
        
        $test->questions()->saveMany($questions);
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Test created successfully', 'test' => $test->load('questions')], 201);
}
```